# HTML5 placeholder inside Struts html:text tag

Tags: html, struts-1

I'm using Struts 1.3.10 in a web application, and I want my textfields to have a placeholder. Unfortunately, the current Struts taglib doesn't recognize this attribute, and I would like to avoid using javascript for this if possible. Do you know any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Struts 1 is dead. It hasn't had a release since 2008. I would really think about migrating to a more modern framework.

If you're stuck with Struts 1, you could

- edit the sources yourself, and add a placeholder attribute to the tag.
- avoid using the tag, and go back to basic HTML + JSTL + EL :

  ```
  <input type="text" name="foo" value="<c:out value='${myForm.foo}' />" 
         placeholder="Enter foo here" />
  ```

Comment: Yes, I know it's an old, crappy framework, but for now we're kinda stuck :(

Comment: I ended up using your second suggestion, although that screws up validations using the validation plugin

Answer (score 0):

In case this might be helpful to others:

If you have a JavaBean (with getters and setters) you could use basic html and the bean:write struts tag.

```html
<input type="text" name="foo" placeholder="Enter foo here"value="<bean:write name="myFormBean" property="foo" />">
```