# How can I put a placeholder in a struts textfield tag?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, struts-1

i got error because am using placeholder attribute in struts tags....

`<html:text property="name" styleClass="form-control" placeholder="some text"/>`

how can resolve the problem,pls help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There is no placeholder tag in struts.use HTML5 input type tag instead.

Comment: You are write @Purnendu

Comment: @KannanPriya You can use simple HTML. No need to add anything extra.

Comment: Alternatively a tooltip might be a solution as well.
<html:text property="name" styleClass="form-control" title="some text"/>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use jQuery `attr` like below:

```
<html:text property="name" styleClass="form-control" styleId="abc" />
```

JavaScript code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#abc").attr("placeholder", "some text");
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Just replace:

```
<html:text property="name" styleClass="form-control" placeholder="some text" />
```

With:

```
<input type="text" name="property" class="form-control" placeholder="some text"
                             │
                             └─── Form property ────┐
                                                    │
       value="<bean:write name="name" property="property" />" />
                                  │                
               Name of form-bean ─┘
```

The value of the attribute `name` must match the property of your form to *trip* in the request.

Comment: Replacing the struts html tag with normal html tag will result in Struts provided default functionalities(i18n and many more) will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

There is a placeholder attribute in struts tags as well called placeholder

```
<s:form action="Welcome">
  <s:textfield name="username" label="Username" placeholder="Enter Your Name" />
  <s:password name="password" label="Password" placeholder="Password"/>
  <s:submit/>
</s:form>
```

**Edit**

There isn't an attribute with the name placeholder (sorry for the confusion), but if you type in placeholder like my code sample, the struts form will be evaluated as below

```
<form id="Welcome" name="Welcome" action="/User/Welcome.action" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="Welcome_username" placeholder="Enter your Name">
  <input type="password" name="password" id="Welcome_password" placeholder="Password">
</form>
```

If you notice, the placeholder attribute renders up just fine with the complete form

Answer (score 1):

You can try with jQuery to add this attribute when document gets ready:

```
<html:text property="name" styleClass="form-control" styleId="xyz" />
```

then try adding this jquery:

```
$(function(){
    $(':input').each(function(){
       $(this).attr("placeholder", this.id);
    });
});
```

or [this answer could help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11827697/1059101)

Answer (score 0):

A simple alternative using javascript event is as follows :

```
<html:text property="username" value="Username" onclick="this.value=''" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to something written above in jQuery, you can try with javascript :

```
<html:text property="name" styleClass="form-control" styleId="myId" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('myId').setAttribute("placeholder", "my personal placeholder");
</script>
```